# Twilio call phone number masking

Tags: java, twilio

We need to connect two customers using voice - but we need to hide customer phone number from each other. We decide to use next approach - [masked phone numbers by twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/java/servlets#connect-via-phone-call)

Question is:

1. We connect two customers using twilio number. **Can we use same number for another call or it is 'busy' until call is completed?**
2. **If it is 'busy' can we buy for example 20 phone numbers and get available each time we need to make call?**

Not related but why there is no possibility to buy Ukrainian phone number.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: is there a possibility of using a center switch? not just a center switch, couple of them switches and you can use that number to show numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first answer your specific questions below :

1. Twilio numbers  can be called as often as you wish while there is already an ongoing call in place. In other words Twilio should never play a fast busy if not explicitly programmed by you .
2. N/A since its not busy .

Coming back to your use case , there are multiple companies who have built Masked Numbers Use case on Twilio and there are multiple strategies that one could use to optimise the number of phone-numbers to use and for association ( permanent or temporary ) of phone numbers to a consumer-producer relation . 
I would recommend having a look at

- https://www.twilio.com/use-cases/marketplace-communications/masked-phone-numbers/build

*PS:* *Since this question was not about strategies for implementation , I have put more details .*

**Update for OP's question in the comment below**

Example :

```
producer      twilio-masking-number                    consumer
aaa                xxx                                   bbb
ccc                xxx                                   ddd
```

Above is an example association that you might store.
In TwiML response for incoming call , check the incoming number . If it is aaa , then destination is bbb , return a TwiML like the one below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+xxx">
        <Number>+bbb</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

If the incoming number is  is bbb , then destination is aaa , return a TwiML like the one below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+xxx">
        <Number>+aaa</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

This way the callerID for all interactions between aaa and bbb will be 'xxx' , hence masking the original phone numbers .

Here's a high level flow diagram

[image]

Comment: Thanks. 

After implementing this feature it looks like it only masks outgoing number. If aaa call xxx twilio makes aaa call bbb. So aaa doesn't know bbb - but bbb knows aaa.

Is there any possibility to hide them both so bbb saw xxx calling?

Comment: Sure , you should store this association  aaa-xxx-bbb somewhere in your app ( as db maybe ) and when aaa calls xxx , you <Dial> bbb . If <bbb> calls xxx , you <Dial> aaa .  You should also have a effective and expiration date for this association dependent on your business logic . Hope this helps ,but if not let me know and i will elaborate with examples .

Comment: I already store this association. Problem is that during aaa xxx call on bbb phone it shows not xxx but aaa so bbb knows aaa phone number.

Comment: @DanyloBatyuk . Are you using caller id (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-caller-id ) attribute to change the display number ?